# Does limit of a quotient (say as $x \to a$) existing implictly imply that the denominator is nonzero for some open interval containing $a$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

In my real analysis class when proving L'Hopital's Rule, we assumed that $\lim_{x \to x_0} f'(x)/g'(x)$ exists. Our professor said that a hidden assumption of this is that $g'(x) \neq 0$ for $x$ near $x_0$ AKA for some open interval containing $x_0$. Note that our definition of limits is the one using limit points, and it doesn't require the function to be defined around a open interval of $x_0$. Since this is our definition of limit, I am confused, can someone explain why assuming $\lim_{x \to x_0} f'(x)/g'(x)$ would imply that $g'(x) \neq 0$ for $x$ near $x_0$?

Comment: I don't think that assuming that limit exists *implies* that $g'$ isn't $0$ in a neighborhood.  There are counterexamples that show that the conclusion of LR is false if that assumption on $g'$ is dropped.

Comment: @Randall, so probably just a mistake by my professor? Also could you share some examples?